# Form1 is being captured even after hiding it

Tags: c#

I'm developing a snipping tool application using c#. When the capture button in Form1 is clicked, I'm hiding Form1 and taking screenshot of background screen, but the problem is in the screenshot the Form1 window is showing even though I'm executing this.Hide(); statement first and then taking the screenshot. Please help me how to make Form1 not appear in the screenshot.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication5
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public static Image fullDesktop;
        public static Image partIamge;
        public static Form backgroundForm;
        public static PictureBox picbox1;

        public static Point mouseDownAt;
        public static Point mouseIsAt;
        public static bool isMouseDown = false;

        public static Color backgroundColor = Color.DarkGray;
        public static int backgroundAlpha = 150;
        public static Color outlineColor = Color.Red;
        public static int outlineWidth = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void Initialize()
        {
            backgroundForm = new Form();
            backgroundForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            backgroundForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            backgroundForm.Cursor = Cursors.Cross;

            picbox1 = new PictureBox();
            picbox1.Size = Screen.FromControl(backgroundForm).Bounds.Size;
            picbox1.Location = new Point(0, 0);
            picbox1.Image = fullDesktop;
            picbox1.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
            picbox1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(OnPaint);
            picbox1.MouseDown += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseDown);
            picbox1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseMove);
            picbox1.MouseUp += new MouseEventHandler(OnMouseUp);
            backgroundForm.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(OnKeyDown);
            backgroundForm.KeyPreview = true;
            backgroundForm.Controls.Add(picbox1);
        }

        public void OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
                backgroundForm.Close();
        }
        public void OnPaint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            SolidBrush opaqueWhiteBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(backgroundAlpha, backgroundColor.R, backgroundColor.G, backgroundColor.B));
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(opaqueWhiteBrush, 0, 0, picbox1.Width, picbox1.Height);

            if (isMouseDown)
            {
                Rectangle pos = getMouseMoveRect;
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(outlineColor, outlineWidth), new Rectangle(pos.X - outlineWidth, pos.Y - outlineWidth, pos.Width + outlineWidth, pos.Height + outlineWidth));
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(partIamge, pos.Location);

                //string displayText = "W: " + pos.Width + " H: " + pos.Height;
                //Font font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                //e.Graphics.DrawString(displayText, font, Brushes.White, pos.X, pos.Y - font.Size - 6, StringFormat.GenericDefault);
            }
        }

        public void OnMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right && !isMouseDown)
            {
                //Application.Exit();
                //backgroundForm.Close();
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                mouseDownAt = e.Location;
                Cursor.Position = new Point(e.Location.X + 1, e.Location.Y + 1);
                mouseIsAt = new Point(e.Location.X + 1, e.Location.Y + 1);
                partIamge = ((Bitmap)fullDesktop).Clone(getMouseMoveRect, fullDesktop.PixelFormat);
                isMouseDown = true;
                picbox1.Refresh();
            }
        }

        public void OnMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isMouseDown)
            {
                mouseIsAt = e.Location;
                Rectangle rect = getMouseMoveRect;
                if (rect.Width != 0 && rect.Height != 0)
                {
                    partIamge = ((Bitmap)fullDesktop).Clone(rect, fullDesktop.PixelFormat);
                    picbox1.Refresh();
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                bool hasMoved = false;

                if (isMouseDown)
                {
                    hasMoved = true;
                    isMouseDown = false;
                }

                SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
                sfd.Filter = "PNG image (*.png)|*.png";
                if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    partIamge.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
                    Clipboard.SetImage(partIamge);
                }
                else
                {
                    hasMoved = false;
                    picbox1.Refresh();
                }

                if (hasMoved)
                {
                    backgroundForm.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        public Rectangle getMouseMoveRect
        {
            get
            {
                int x = 0;
                int y = 0;
                int width = 0;
                int height = 0;

                if (mouseIsAt.X > mouseDownAt.X)
                {
                    x = mouseDownAt.X;
                    width = mouseIsAt.X - mouseDownAt.X;
                }
                else
                {
                    x = mouseIsAt.X;
                    width = mouseDownAt.X - mouseIsAt.X;
                }

                if (mouseIsAt.Y > mouseDownAt.Y)
                {
                    y = mouseDownAt.Y;
                    height = mouseIsAt.Y - mouseDownAt.Y;
                }
                else
                {
                    y = mouseIsAt.Y;
                    height = mouseDownAt.Y - mouseIsAt.Y;
                }

                return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            }
        }

        public Image CaptureScreen
        {
            get
            {
                Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.X,
                             Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Y,
                             0, 0,
                             image.Size,
                             CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
                }

                return image;
            }
        }

        private void cmdCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            this.Hide();

            fullDesktop = CaptureScreen;
            Initialize();

            backgroundForm.ShowDialog();
            this.Show();
        }

        private void cmdExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void Form1_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void cmdFullCapture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            this.Hide();

            while (IsOnScreen(this)) ;
            fullDesktop = CaptureScreen;
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "PNG image (*.png)|*.png";
            if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                fullDesktop.Save(sfd.FileName, ImageFormat.Png);
                Clipboard.SetImage(partIamge);
            }
            this.Show();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

    }
}
```

---

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Guessing but I'd say capture is firing before the form processes the request to hide. An eventhandler that fires once the form is hidden should do the trick.

Comment: could you tell me how to do it.

Comment: The VisibleChanged event of teh form you want to hide should do. You could just move your capture code into it, call your capture code from it, or add an Oncaptureevent to your code and trigger it from the visible changed event. Not sure whether the event is called when visible property changes of is about to, so you might need a delay or a doevents call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem on old Windows versions, you capture the pixels in the video adapter's frame buffer.  When you hide your window, other windows need to repaint themselves first to update the pixels in the buffer that once were drawn by your window.  That takes time, an unpredictable amount of time.  You don't wait at all so you still get the old pixels of your window.

There is a simple workaround for this, you can also use your form's Opacity property to hide a window.  Opacity is implemented by *layering* inside the video adapter itself.  Set the Opacity to 99 in the designer.  Which is actually enough, your window won't be captured anymore.  This is actually a bug, it got fixed in Windows 8.  So don't leave it that way, set the Opacity to 0 in your code before the screen-shot, back to 0.99 afterwards (not a typo).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try change `WindowState` of your Form programatically:

Instead of:

```
this.Hide();
```

Try:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

And after take your screenshot:

```
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply Selman22. But I'm still facing the same issue. Form1 is still appearing in the screenshot even after minimizing the Form1 window.